# Uncaught TypeError in View

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I'm following the instructions in an Odoo development book for making a view, and I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Type is not a constructor` when I load the following view.  If I take out the `<search>` element in my code (on lines 11-15), the page loads correctly.  What do I have wrong about the `<search>` tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_tree_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">To-do Task Form</field>
        <field name="model">todo.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree decoration-muted="is_done==True">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="is_done"/>
            </tree>
            <search>
                <field name="name"/>
                <filter string="Not Done" domain="[('is_done','=',False)]"/>
                <filter string="Done" domain="[('is_done','!=',False)]"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="view_form_todo_task" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">To-do Task Form</field>
        <field name="model">todo.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="To-do Task">
                <header>
                    <button class="oe_highlight" name="do_toggle_done" string="Toggle Done" type="object"/>
                    <button name="do_clear_done" string="Clear All Done" type="object"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group name="group_top">
                        <group name="group_left">
                            <field name="name"/>
                        </group>
                        <group name="group_right">
                            <field name="is_done"/>
                            <field name="active" readonly="1"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code itself (fields, domain, etc.) look fine. I think the problem may be with including the search node in the same view definition. Typically the search view is defined separately.

Take a look at the [views documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#search) for more details on how to create it.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.